# Can I do yum queries as a non-privileged user?

Tags: permissions, yum

I would guess that as a non-privileged user, I can't do `yum install` or `yum update`, and that is understandable. But I would have thought I am able to do `yum search` or `yum whatprovides`. These commands should not make any changes to my local system, and just query what is in the repositories.

When trying to run `yum search` or `yum whatprovides` as a non-privileged user however, I get an error such as:

```
bash-4.2$ yum search openssh-server
ovl: Error while doing RPMdb copy-up:                                           
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/lib/rpm/.dbenv.lock'                        


 One of the configured repositories failed (Unknown),                           
 and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only    
 safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:        

     1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.

     2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working  
        upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer            
        distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the       
        packages for the previous distribution release still work).             

     3. Run the command with the repository temporarily disabled                
            yum --disablerepo=<repoid> ...                                      

     4. Disable the repository permanently, so yum won't use it by default. Yum 
        will then just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it    
        again or use --enablerepo for temporary usage:                          

            yum-config-manager --disable <repoid>                               
        or                                                                      
            subscription-manager repos --disable=<repoid>                       

     5. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.   
        Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands, 
        so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much   
        slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice 
        compromise:                                                             

            yum-config-manager --save --setopt=<repoid>.skip_if_unavailable=true

Cannot find repomd.xml file for rhel7-x86_64-730                                
bash-4.2$
```

After logging in as root and chmoding this `.dbenv.lock` to 666, now my non-privileged user can `yum search` but not `yum whatprovides`.

```
bash-4.2$ yum search openssh-server
Loaded plugins: ovl, product-id, search-disabled-repos
ovl: Error while doing RPMdb copy-up:
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/lib/rpm/__db.002'
========================= N/S matched: openssh-server ==========================
gsi-openssh-server.x86_64 : SSH server daemon with GSI authentication
openssh-server.x86_64 : An open source SSH server daemon
openssh-server-sysvinit.x86_64 : The SysV initscript to manage the OpenSSH
                               : server.

  Name and summary matches only, use "search all" for everything.
bash-4.2$  

bash-4.2$ yum whatprovides sshd                                                 
Loaded plugins: ovl, product-id, search-disabled-repos                          
ovl: Error while doing RPMdb copy-up:                                           
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/lib/rpm/__db.002'                           


 One of the configured repositories failed (Unknown),                           
 and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only    
 safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:        

     1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.

     2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working  
        upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer            
        distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the       
        packages for the previous distribution release still work).             

     3. Run the command with the repository temporarily disabled
            yum --disablerepo=<repoid> ...

     4. Disable the repository permanently, so yum won't use it by default. Yum
        will then just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it
        again or use --enablerepo for temporary usage:

            yum-config-manager --disable <repoid>
        or
            subscription-manager repos --disable=<repoid>

     5. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
        Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
        so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much
        slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
        compromise:

            yum-config-manager --save --setopt=<repoid>.skip_if_unavailable=true

Caching enabled but no local cache of /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7Server/rhel7-x86_64
-730/856d5d541d62809b07538e7b8b666e115e9871a9-filelists.sqlite.bz2 from rhel7-x8
6_64-730
bash-4.2$
```

Is this because yum will automatically fetch things into the cache during such a query operation, and fails if the cache is not writable? What file permissions would I (as root) need to give to non-privileged users so that they can run these yum queries (e.g. write access to some cache folders)?

PS: root can `yum install` things fine, so it's not a problem with connectivity to the yum repository server per se.

EDIT: After chmoding all files in the `/var/lib/rpm` directory to 666, and also disabling the `ovl` plugin, I don't get the initial errors when running `yum`, but still can't run `yum whatprovides`:

```
bash-4.2$ yum --disableplugin=ovl whatprovides apropos                          
Loaded plugins: product-id, search-disabled-repos                               


 One of the configured repositories failed (Unknown),                           
 and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only    
 safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:        

     1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.

     2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working  
        upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer            
        distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the       
        packages for the previous distribution release still work).             

     3. Run the command with the repository temporarily disabled                
            yum --disablerepo=<repoid> ...                                      

     4. Disable the repository permanently, so yum won't use it by default. Yum 
        will then just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it    
        again or use --enablerepo for temporary usage:                          

            yum-config-manager --disable <repoid>                               
        or                                                                      
            subscription-manager repos --disable=<repoid>                       

     5. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
        Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
        so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much
        slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
        compromise:

            yum-config-manager --save --setopt=<repoid>.skip_if_unavailable=true

Caching enabled but no local cache of /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7Server/rhel7-x86_64
-730/856d5d541d62809b07538e7b8b666e115e9871a9-filelists.sqlite.bz2 from rhel7-x8
6_64-730
```

Answer (score 2):

Newer versions of yum allow you to perform non-intrusive operations as a normal user. With older versions you'll need to use `repoquery` instead, in the `yum-utils` package.

Additionally, it seems that the ovl plugin is causing the issue, not yum per se. You can pass `--disableplugin=ovl` to disable it temporarily.

Comment: see my edit -> disabling ovl did not help. also I'm running yum 3.4.3, is this version too old? later I'll try installing `yum-utils`

Comment: I have no idea what version would be too old at this point; I'm running Fedora which has switched to dnf, which supports (some) non-superuser actions.

Comment: Okay I installed `yum-utils` and tried to run `repoquery --whatprovides sshd` as an unprivileged user (just for example), but it just prints "Error: Could not make cachedir, exiting" and exits. What permissions do I (as root) need to set to make `repoquery` work properly?

Comment: @Kidburla Your user needs a home directory.

Comment: @MichaelHampton is there any way around this? as the user does not have a username and/or entry in `/etc/passwd`

Comment: @Kidburla Then the user can't really be said to exist on the system...